# PHP Update cart query is not woring

Tags: php, html, mysql, function

I am creating a shopping cart for my ecommerce website, but in that my update query program is not working. If more than one product is present in my cart then it is not updating the price & product quantity. If one product is present then it is working fine. I am new in php. I am also attaching the screenshot of my cart.

// cart.php

```
<?php include_once("header.php");?>
<div id="products_box">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <table align="center" width="700" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
 <br>
 <tr align="center">
  <td style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px" colspan="4"><h2> Your Book(s) Details </h2></td>
 </tr>

 <tr align="center" style="font-size:20px; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'">
 <th>Remove</th>
 <th>Book(s)</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 <th>Total Price</th>
 </tr>

 <?php
 $total=0;
 global $con;
 $ip = getIp();
 $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";
 $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price))
 {
  $b_id = $p_price['cb_id'];
  $b_price = "select * from books where b_id='$b_id'";
  $run_book_price = mysqli_query($con, $b_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_book_price))
  {
   $b_price = array($pp_price['b_price']);
   $b_title = $pp_price['b_title'];
   $b_image = $pp_price['b_image'];
   $single_price = $pp_price['b_price'];

   $values = array_sum($b_price);
   $total += $values;

 ?>

 <tr align="center"> 
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]"  value="<?php echo $b_id; ?>"/> </td>
 <td><h3><a href='details.php?b_id=$b_id' style='text-decoration:none; color: #005680;'><?php echo $b_title; ?></a></h3>
 <img src="admin_area/books_images/<?php echo $b_image; ?>" width="100" height="100" />
 </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="qty"  size="8" value=""/></td>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['update_qty']))
 { 

   $qty = $_POST['qty'];
   $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";
   $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty) or die(mysqli_error($con));
   $total = $total*$qty;

 }

 ?>
 <td> <?php echo "Rs.\n". $single_price; ?></td>
 </tr>

 <?php  } }?>

 <tr align="right">
   <td colspan="4"><b> Sub Total: </b></td>
   <td colspan="4"><?php echo "Rs.\n". $total; ?></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:12px"><input type="submit" name="remove_pro" value="Remove" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF"/></td>


  <td align="center" style="padding-right:20px"><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF" /></td>


   <td align="center" style="padding-left:12px"><input type="submit" name="update_qty" value="Update Quantity" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF"/></td>


  <td align="right" colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF; margin-right:10px"/></td>
  </tr>

 </table>

 </form>


 <?php

  global $con;
  $ip = getIp();

  if(isset($_POST['remove_pro']))
 {
  foreach($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id)
 {
  $delete_pro = "delete from cart where cb_id='$remove_id' AND ip_add='$ip'";
  $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $delete_pro) or die(mysqli_error($con));
  if($run_query)
  {
   echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
  }
 }
}

 if(isset($_POST['continue']))
{
 echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}

 if(isset($_POST['checkout']))
{
 echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>";
}


 ?>

</div>


</div>



</div>
<!--Content Wrapper Ends--->


<?php include_once("footer.php");?>
<!--Main Wrapper Ends-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the status report. Was there a *question* you meant to ask?

Comment: I am having a problem in updating the content in my cart.php

Comment: "it is not working" is *not* a question. "a problem updating the content" is *not* a question.

Comment: update cart is not working

Comment: The UPDATE statement looks like it is going to update *every* row in the cart table. Are you sure there shouldn't be a WHERE clause? I don't see much evidence of statements to aid in debugging. An echo or a print of the variables containing the SQL text, before it's executed. And echo or print that outputs a notice of which path the code execution is taking after a conditional branch. StackOverflow isn't a debugging service. [https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "update cart is not working, here's my code" is *not* a question. StackOverflow is a question answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: can you please provide me the php code to update the product when user enter the quantity. I Know about the stackoverflow website & my question is not relating to debugging process.

Comment: Dude, I've tried to help you. I understand, your question isn't about the debugging process. But that seems to be *exactly* what your current code needs... a debugging process. And I don't see any artifacts or evidence of any debugging that has been done. I suggest you narrow down where the problem is. I don't see even an echo of $_POST['update_qty'].  Does that isset evaluate to true? Is your code even branching into that block? A dump of non working code and "give me the codez plz" is *not* a question.

Comment: this is the only code that i  had now & i had tested this code many time. When more than one product is present then update php block is not working. Do u have any suggestions. I am new to php & i don't know y i need the echo of $_POST['update_qty']